# How to show code snippet in django template, "|safe" filter not helps

Tags: django, templates, filter, tags

I'm trying to make app like gist.github.com. After saving code snippets they looks in like long string. I tried different filters like "safe, escape ... etc". Nothing helped me.

In database code looks like:

```
def asd(a):
    return a+2                                                     
asd(2)
```

This is my template code:

```
<div>{{ s.code|escape }}</div>
```

Result is:

> def asd(a): return a+2 asd(2)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have anything to do with escaping or marking as safe. In fact, it doesn't have anything to do with Django at all.

HTML ignores whitespace, including newlines. If you want to show your code as formatted in the db you should use the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it helped you.